# Naming Externalized Images via MD5 Sum

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I have a large presentation with over 200 figures (mainly created through stepping through each image).  I'm using the external library to cache the results to great effect.  Each figure is cached in a numbered file e.g., `document_name-figure105`.  However, when I add a new image at the beginning of the talk, it causes all the images to move by one, e.g., 
`document_name-figure105` is now `document_name-figure106`, and each now is re-rendered because the MD5 sum has changed.  Is there a way of naming each externalized figure by its MD5 sum to avoid this problem?

Comment: I've always thought it would be handy if I could base the filename for the figure on the filename for the code for the figure since I usually have that separate and use `\input`. But I can't even figure out a way to do that.

Comment: Using the md5 sum as file name is no supported use case currently. You could consider `figure name/.add={}{section1_}` in order to number images inside of sections. If that would help, I could elaborate on the details. The problem as such would remain, but only inside of sections.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I'd be happy to try my hand at submitting a patch to add this functionality.  What's the best way to go about this?  Until then, I'll just use tikzsetnextfilename as Heiko Oberdiek suggests (I also use cfr's approach of putting each figure in a separate file).

Comment: @Jeff the current implementation of the external lib computes the "next file name" and computes the MD5 afterwards. The up-to-date check happens in `\tikzexternal@check@uptodate@mode` in `tikzexternalshared.code.tex`. Feel free to work with it. Keep in mind that md5 sums are only available in `pdftex` and `luatex`, so your feature would be unsupported for all other drivers.

Answer (score 2):

See `\tikzsetnextfilename` in the TikZ manual. This allows individual names for the figures. MD5 sum names have the disadvantage, that each change would generate new file. Then the disc space would be filled with outdated garbage.

Comment: I agree that if you're not careful, you could end up with a lot of garbage.  Couldn't we just remove the files with MD5 hashes that are not currently used?

Comment: They also have the advantage that if the same picture appears twice in the doc (or 19 times as several on my doc) it is only compiled once ! It would bring down 798 figures to 199, saving 20 min compile time...