# De-duplicating a large number of tikz figures

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I have a document with a huge (790) number of figures, a lot of them are small trees with various labels. I've externalized the figures to shorten the compile time (25min). However, lots (94 of them) of figures appear several times (upto 19 times). There are actually 199 unique figures (computed from the md5):

```
cat *.md5 | sort | uniq | wc -l
199
```

So I would like to automatically detect identical figures and ensure that they are compiled only once. Lots of figures are generated by macros such as

```
\newcommand{\op}[1]{
    \foreach \letters in {#1} {
            \StrLeft{\letters}{1}[\firstletter]
            \StrRight{\letters}{1}[\lastletter]
            \IfEqCase{\lastletter}{%
                    {a}{\red}%
                    {b}{\blue}%
                    {c}{\green}%
                    {f}{\bf}%
            }%
            \hspace{-.1mm}
            \IfEqCase{\firstletter}{%
                    {l}{\prec}%
                    {m}{\prec\hspace*{-.27cm}\succ}%
                    {r}{\succ}%
                    {o}{\odot}%
                    {*}{\color{gray}\prec}%
                    {n}{\color{white}\prec}%
            } \hspace{-.1mm}
    }
}
\newcommand{\compoR}[2]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-.5cm, level 1/.style={sibling distance = .8cm, level distance = .6cm}, level 2/.style={sibling distance = .8cm, level distance = .5cm}]
            \node [rectangle, draw] {$\op{#1}$}
                    child {node {}}
                    child {node [rectangle, draw] {$\op{#2}$}
                            child {node {}}
                            child {node {}}
                    }
            ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
} % right composition
```

This allows to describe them as `\compoR{r,l}{r,l}` in the text, leading to equations such as

```
\compoR{l,l}{*,*} = \compoR{l,r}{*,l} + \compoR{l,r}{*,r}
```

There are tons of such equations, and that's why we have so many duplicated figures.

Now, if it were possible to name figures after their MD5 sum as in

[Naming Externalized Images via MD5 Sum](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240395/naming-externalized-images-via-md5-sum)

that would solve my problem, but I can't manage to do it. Due to the large number of figures, I don't want to do the de-duplication by hand. I'm wondering if there is another way I overlooked?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks

Comment: If the TikZ picture is only dependent on `#1` and `#2` which seem to just contain simple text (and no weird characters unsuitable for TeX or a filesystem) you could just set the next filename to, say, `fig-#1-#2` but as I understand it, it will still externalize each picture since it will just increment a suffix. Though, this might be able to be tricked with some hacky patchwork by resetting that internal suffix.